# Keystore not generating

Tags: codenameone, keytool, signing

I am following the codename one instructions for generating a keystore using the keytool command prompt, but I keep getting errors. My last attempt was something like this (I won't be using exactly what I put):

keytool -genkey -keystore Keystore.ks -alias Kamilah/company -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 15000 -dname "CN=Kamilah Carlisle, OU=ou, O=comp, L=Richmond, S=Virginia, C=US" -storepass password -keypass samepasswordAsStorepass

This gave me a keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Keystore.ks (Access is denied). P.S. I have seen a couple of questions posted on stack overflow with this issue, but I don't think I have any commas or spaces where they don't belong so I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clientkeystore Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520362/clientkeystore-access-is-denied) - I answered this question here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to create a keystore file in a directory you don't have access to write. (Or maybe your .ks file already exist and you can't modifiy it)
If you are on Windows , try to change the path you execute your command , execute it in your personnal folder or your desktop. An other way is to launch command prompt as an Administrator.

Comment: FYI you can also create this in our preferences or in the Codename One Preferences GUI.