# clientkeystore Access is denied

Tags: java, keytool, android-keystore

When I want to create a keystore with `keytool`, I get an access denied error message. See below

```
PS C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin> .\keytool.exe -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  ...
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  ...
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  ...
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  ...
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  ...
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  ..
Is CN=..., OU=..., O=..., L=..., ST=..., C=.. correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <client>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: clientkeystore (Access is denied)
PS C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on JDK 1.8.0_171 and then resolve it.

Basically, you are getting an access denied for writing the file:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\clientkeystore
```

You need to do one of the following:

Run the command from your home directory and specify the full path to the keystore binary.

```
PS> cd $HOME;
PS> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\keytool.exe -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
```

Specify a path to the `clientkeystore` file which you have write access to. In this example I am using your home directory:

```
PS> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin
PS> .\keytool.exe -keystore $HOME\clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
```

(I would recommend this) Append the JDK bin directory to you Path environment variable and also specify a directory which you have access to:

```
PS> $env:Path += "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin"
PS> keytool.exe -keystore $HOME\clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
```

Done.